# Empty space at the end of parent layout when adjustViewBounds is added on children

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My custom control in real layout

```
    <CustomControl.CustomRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_star_height"
        app:rating="4"
        app:spacing="@dimen/small_star_margin"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/primary_gray_color"/>
```

My custom control

```
namespace CustomControl
{
    public class CustomRatingBar : LinearLayout
    {
        public int Rating => _rating;

        private int _rating = 5;
        private int _numStars = 5;
        private int _height;
        private int _spacing;

        private Drawable _filledDrawable;
        private Drawable _emptyDrawable;

        public CustomRatingBar(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            Init();
        }

        public CustomRatingBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            Init(attrs);
        }

        public CustomRatingBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
            Init(attrs);
        }

        public CustomRatingBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        {
            Init(attrs);
        }

        public void SetRating(int rating)
        {
            if (rating == -1)
            {
                Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i += 2)
            {
                var child = (ImageView)GetChildAt(i);

                if (i < rating * 2)
                {
                    if ((bool)child.Tag == true)
                        continue;

                    else
                    {
                        child.SetImageDrawable(_filledDrawable);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    child.SetImageDrawable(_emptyDrawable);
                }
            }
        }
        private void Init(IAttributeSet attrs = null)
        {
            InitParams(attrs);
            VerifyParams();
            InitView();
        }

        private void InitParams(IAttributeSet attrs)
        {
            TypedArray typedArray = Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs);
            _rating = typedArray.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_rating, _rating);
            _numStars = typedArray.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_numStars, _numStars);
            _spacing = (int)typedArray.GetDimension(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_spacing, 0);

            _filledDrawable = typedArray.HasValue(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_srcVectorFilled)
                ? VectorDrawableCompat.Create(Resources, typedArray.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_srcVectorFilled, View.NoId), null)
                : null;
            _emptyDrawable = typedArray.HasValue(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_srcVectorEmpty)
                ? VectorDrawableCompat.Create(Resources, typedArray.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.RatingBarAttrs_srcVectorEmpty, View.NoId), null)
                : null;

            typedArray.Recycle();

            var builtInSet = Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.LayoutHeight });
            try
            {
                _height = (int)builtInSet.GetDimension(0, 0);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _height = (int)Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.small_star_height);
            }

            builtInSet.Recycle();
        }

        private void VerifyParams()
        {
            if (_numStars < 1)
                _numStars = 5;

            if (_rating < 0 || _rating > _numStars)
                _rating = _numStars;

            if (_filledDrawable == null)
            {
                _filledDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.Create(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_star_filled, null);
            }

            if (_emptyDrawable == null)
            {
                _emptyDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.Create(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_star_empty, null);
            }
        }

        private void InitView()
        {
            Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Horizontal;
            var spacePar = new LayoutParams(_spacing, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            var starPar = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, _height);

            for (int i = 0; i < _numStars; i++)
            {
                var starView = new ImageView(Context);
                starView.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);

                if (i <= _rating - 1)
                {
                    starView.Tag = true;
                    starView.SetImageDrawable(_filledDrawable);
                    AddView(starView, starPar);
                }
                else
                {
                    starView.SetImageDrawable(_emptyDrawable);
                    AddView(starView, starPar);
                }

                if (i == _numStars - 1)
                    break;  

                AddView(new Space(Context), spacePar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result if i set starView.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);

[image]

Result if i do not set starView.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);

[image]

I want to ask everyone how i can remove empty space of the end of LinearLayout when i adjustViewBounds of all my stars.

Thank everyone very much!!

Comment: Could you provide more details of CustomControl for me to reproduce?

Comment: I have just updated my control above. I think I fixed that by
```
            typedArray.Recycle();

            var builtInSet = Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.LayoutHeight });
            try
            {
                _height = (int)builtInSet.GetDimension(0, 0);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _height = (int)Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.small_star_height);
            }

            builtInSet.Recycle();
```